# Is it possible to restore data from browsing session in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, session, caching, browser, restore

Lets say, one visited a Website, which loaded a js-module.
This module loaded some information into a form and the chrome browser displayed it.
Is it anyhow possible to restore this information (i.e. via the browser cache) and view it?

What I've tried so far:

- View Source of Web-Page in Chrome, but i did not record the communication, so no data here
- installed "ChromeCacheView v2.21 - Cache viewer for Google Chrome Web browser" and viewed the Files with Dates which correspond to the concerning session time

Regarding the second point: I can only view the js-files unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it depends on what device you are on. If you are on the computer, go into your google history and find the website you need. Then, you can copy the link and save it somewhere else.

Also, if you don't know how to get into your history, click control h.

Comment: This is not, what I asked for. Of course I know, that the URLs to the visited Websites is saved. But lets say you had access to a website, which is not granted anymore now. When you revisit the website through this URL you wont be able to see anything because you do not have the permission to, anymore.

Comment: It was not easy to understand, so I'm sorry about that. Now what you're asking, I'm not sure that's possible.